# How to add tools from Heron Mapping Client into Boundless SDK GXP template?

Tags: boundless-suite, heron-mapping-client, gxp

I am creating my first online map application using the Boundless SDK GXP template from OpenGeoSuite 4.8. I have been able to successfully edit the template to add in plugins and widgets from GXP, but am trying to figure out how to add additional functionality. Ideally, I would like to have a panel or box that lets the user search a WFS and zoom to the the feature they searched for.

I came across the [FormSearchCenter tool](http://lib.heron-mc.org/heron/1.0.6/examples/formsearchcenter/index.html) from Heron Mapping Client (the Config.js for this tool is [here](http://lib.heron-mc.org/heron/1.0.6/examples/formsearchcenter/Config.js)) that has this functionality. However, I am unclear as to how to integrate it into the app.js I created using the Boundless SDK GXP template.

Does anyone know of any sites or tutorials I can look at to learn how to integrate this tool into my Boundless SDK GXP app.js? Or have any guidance on if this is possible? I've exhausted the Application Development with Boundless SDK GXP template tutorial and haven't come across anything online about this.

Answer (score 1):

I would direct this question to stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/

Customizing the SDK is possible and requires more development.

the New version of the Boundless SDK is available https://sdk.boundlessgeo.com/

You may find it easier to customize.